# creating a file using a variable name in current directory in c#

Tags: c#

Suppose I have  string variable **string id='sample'**. I want to make a file named sample.txt in my current directory (Environment.CurrentDirectory) using the string variable and after that I want to get the full path of the text file. How will I do that? Normally we can create a text file(say: sample.txt) in current directory
in this way:

```
    string path=Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string FileName = path + "\\sample.txt";
    File.Create(FileName);
```

But how will I do this using the string variable and after creation how will I get the full path of the sample.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
string path=Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string FileName = Path.Combine(path, id + ".txt";
File.Create(FileName);
```

and at this point you have already the full path name in the FileName variable but you can use other methods of the [Path class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
string fullPathName = Path.GetFullPath(FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help:

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory() + "\\" + id + ".txt";
```